# Assigning a dereferenced shared_ptr

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, shared-ptr, dereference

Consider the following class:

```
struct MyClass {
    int mId;
    MyClass(int id): mId(id) {}
   ~MyClass() { std::cout << "deleting: " << mId << std::endl; }
};
```

And the usage:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> p(new MyClass(0));
MyClass& m = *p;
m = MyClass(2);
```

The result is:

```
deleting: 2
deleting: 2
```

Please help me understanding:

1. Why there are two `MyClass(2)` objects (assumption made on the destructor logs)
2. Is this a memory leak? Shouldn't the `MyClass(0)` leak?

Thank you.

Comment: Put prints in "Constructor/Copy Constructor/Assignment/Destructor" then you can see creation and destruction more clearly.

Comment: Uh.. @LokiAstari you made me feel very embarrassed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no memory leak. This code:

```
m = MyClass(2);
```

creates a temporary object of type `MyClass` which is copied into `m` using the (default-generated) copy assignment operator of `MyClass`, and then destructed. Eventually, `p` runs out of scope and its destructor destroys the `MyClass` instance to which is points (the one bound to `m`).

If we spelled out all the implicit calls explicitly, this is happening:

```
// std::shared_ptr<MyClass> p(new MyClass(0));
tmp1.MyClass(0);
p.shared_ptr(&tmp1);

// MyClass& m = *p;
p.operator* ();

// m = MyClass(2);
tmp2.MyClass(2);
m.operator= (tmp2);
tmp2.~MyClass();

// p goes out of scope
p.~shared_ptr();
tmp1.~MyClass();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a thorough answer, Angew!

Answer (score 2):

Do this for a more clear picture of creation destruction:

```
struct MyClass {
    int mId;
    MyClass(int id): mId(id) {std::cout << "Creating: " << this << "(" << mId << ")\n";}
   ~MyClass()                {std::cout << "Deleting: " << this << "(" << mId << ")\n";}
    MyClass(MyClass const& c)
                             {std::cout << "Copy:     " << this << "(" << mId << ")\n"
                                           "    From: " << &c   << "(" << c.mId << ")\n";
                              mId=c.mId;
                             }
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass const& c)
                             {std::cout << "Assign:   " << this << "(" << mId << ")\n"
                                           "    From: " << &c   << "(" << c.mId << ")\n";
                              mId=c.mId;
                             }
};
```

When I run I get:

```
Creating: 0x7fc741c000e0(0)
Creating: 0x7fff50ac38c0(2)
Assign:   0x7fc741c000e0(0)
    From: 0x7fff50ac38c0(2)
Deleting: 0x7fff50ac38c0(2)
Deleting: 0x7fc741c000e0(2)
```